# How to make one-way collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I want to make a one-sided collider so that the player can pass through it only from left to right. What is the easiest way? I would not want to use a script.
[image: Sketch of intended bouncer]

SOLUTION: The standard gaming 3D object "plane" is a one-sided collider. It is located in the main menu of the Uniyt 3D constructor - GameObject / 3D Object / Plane. This plane is visible from the side of the collider and is invisible from the side where it can be crossed. For invisibility on both sides, you need to remove the check mark from the "Renderer Mesh" component. For 2D projects, another special technology is provided - it allows you to make one-sided rigid platforms for jumping on them perpendicularly from the bottom to up. Purpose for this I using the one-way property of the collider of the standard Unity plane.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to change its meaning, particularly after other users have responded. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create the animations in Autodesk Maya or Autodesk 3DS Max. After that you can import the animations into Unity3D and use them on your specific characters.
You can find plenty of tutorials for both those programs just by google it.

Comment: Thx for your help, I'll try to search on Google.

Answer (score 2):

For your scenario, you can do the following:

Set the collider as a trigger collider by default so you can pass through it. After you pass through it, the collider gets triggered using `OnTriggerEnter(Collider)`, wait a bit until object isn't touching the collider using a coroutine, set to the collider to normal collider (not trigger) using `Collider.isTrigger = false`

Cheers!